# To play VOD streams in chrome using videojs

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, html5-video, video.js

I am trying to play an HLS stream (.m3u8) containing `.ts` file buffers. 
It was playing all right before when i tried with some open sources. Now when i am trying to play with the streams provided by my service provider, It does play in all major browsers except chrome. 
P.s: I am using `videojs` for accomplishing these. I also tested using viblast but no luck there.

For reference i am posting my code :

```
<script>
//myplayer is my <video> object for videojs
myPlayer.src({
      type: "application/x-mpegURL; application/vnd.apple.mpegurl",
      src: encodeURI(some m3u8 link)
});
myPlayer.play();
</script>
```

Now this code here is ruling all browsers but when it faces chrome it kneels down.

The error response from chrome is like below :

> VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:3 MEDIA_ERR_DECODE) The media playback was
>   aborted due to a corruption problem or because the media used features
>   your browser did not support.
>
> MediaError {code: 3, message: "The media playback was aborted due to a
>   corruption…media used features your browser did not support."}
>
> Note: I am getting my streams from `scaleEngine.`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error when using an Mp4 with a Webm fallback. Everything worked well in Firefox but I was getting this error in Chrome. I switched the order of fallbacks so that videojs used Webm first and Mp4 as a fallback. This fixed it for me at least.